# Problems with media and migrations

Tags: python, django, django-migrations, django-media

have problems.
1)In production Django tries to access photos at http://"ip_address"/images/"image".jpg  URL however images must be in http://"ip_address"/media/images/"image".jpg
2)I have added two more fields (alt and text) to existing model. Migrations work and show that the fields are added but i can not see them in the admin panel ( I have added them to the list_display) and i can not access them in my templates.

```
   settings for media
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = 'http://"ip_address"/media/'

urls
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
from django.conf import settings
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',

    url(r'^$','main.views.mainpage'),


)+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()

models
from django.db import models

class Slider(models.Model):
        image = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'images/')
        caption = models.TextField()
        alt = models.CharField(max_length = 20, default = "an image")
        text = models.CharField(max_length = 5, null=True)
admin
from django.contrib import admin
from main.models import Slider

class SliderAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('image','alt','caption','text')

admin.site.register(Slider,SliderAdmin)
```

Comment: Please ask one question per question, since the two question you ask here are unrelated (even if in the same Django project).

Comment: You might want to remove the `static` helper function from your `urlpatterns`; that's for `DEBUG` mode only, not for production mode.

Comment: Thanks @Evert i did not know about it

Answer (score 0):

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/

Add a STATIC_URL to your settings.py

Comment: I have it in my settings it is STATIC_URL='/static/'

Comment: The documentation, https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/staticfiles/